# Return the values of one array, but exclude the values of the second array

Tags: php, arrays

I have the following two arrays:
[image: the 2 arrays]

> Question:
>   How can i  make a 3th array containing the values of the first one
>   **excluding** the values of the second one?

*Additional information:*

*The first one is named $checked, the second one is named $exclude.*
*The values to be excluded are always stored in the second array.*
*The arrays can change in length, values, and order.*

*So that in this case i get this result:*

```
     Array ( [0] => 26 [1] => 28 [2] => 34 ) <-- array 3:
```

Comment: Feel free to edit the title, i had a had a hard time formulating the question. I will stay online until it is answered so feel free to ask for more details.

Comment: Simply use `array_diff` function of PHP. [Check This](https://3v4l.org/g4k55)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$checked = array(11, 26, 38, 13);
$excludeValues = array(26, 38);

foreach ($excludeValues as $exclude) {

    if ($key = array_search ( $exclude , $checked )) {
        unset($checked[$key]);
    }

}

print_r($checked);
```

Answer (score 2):

you can use [`array_diff()`](http://php.net/manual/de/function.array-diff.php):

```
$checked = array(26,28,34,39,41);
$exclude = array(39, 41);
$result = array_diff($checked, $exclude);
print_r($result);
```

Result:

```
Array ( [0] => 26 [1] => 28 [2] => 34 )
```

Comment: I replaced the example from the documentation with your numbers. Better?

Answer (score 1):

Loop through the first array, then check if the value is present in the second array, if not, add it the the third array. Or use the array_diff function as proposed by Uchiha.

```
foreach($array1 as $items){
    if(!in_array($array2,$item)){
        $array3[] = $item
    }
}
```